# how milton webdav work with ms office 2013

Tags: ms-office, webdav, milton

how milton webdav work with ms office 2013? webdav work fine,but can't open ms word. if I need milton enterpise editon?

```
 window.open("ms-excel:ofe|u|"+url, '','');
```

Any suggestion?thanks advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, MS Office and most other major OS vendors require locking, which is available in milton's enterprise edition

If using the annotations framework (recommended) you only need to implement @UniqueID methods for editable types, and milton will provide locking support.

If using the Resource API (ie you are implementing interfaces, instead of using annotations) then you need to implement LockableResource. And you need to implement LockingCollectionResource to have support for Mac Finder.

More information is available on the milton tutorials -

Getting started with the annotations framework:
http://milton.io/programs/milton/anno/anno1/

Implementing file operations with annotations (inc locking):
http://milton.io/programs/milton/anno/anno2/